# Reload all chrome tabs of a certain page with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to reload all tabs of Chrome (i could have many windows open) of a certain page. This is what I did:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set {ids} to every window
    repeat with id in ids
        reload (tabs of window id whose URL contains "mypage.com")
    end repeat
end tell
```

But I get `Google Chrome got an error: Can’t make item 1 of window id 1 into type integer.`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave and Chrome.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to set allTabs to a reference to (tabs of windows whose URL contains "mypage.com") 
tell application "Google Chrome" to reload allTabs
```

Comment: Or just `tell application "Google Chrome" to reload (tabs of windows whose URL contains "mypage.com")`

Answer (score 1):

The answer submitted by @wch1zpink won't work if there are any *Chrome* windows open that **don't** contain at least one tab with a `mypage.com` URL.  Unfortunately, you need to iterate through the windows:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to repeat with W in windows
    reload (every tab in W whose URL contains "mypage.com")
end repeat
```